# ZendFRamework 2 modules

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have been programing with ZF1 and there is a feature I can't found or I'am confused about it. For example one of my current app in ZF1 has this directory structure:

```
libray
app
   -Bootstrap.php
   -layouts
   -models
   -modules
      -admin
         -controllers
         -views
      -neas
         -controllers
         -views
public
```

Where my routing can be: www.domain.com/admin/users/edit or www.domain.com/news/publish/edit

What would be the way to do the same in ZF2?

Comment: Understand [this Section of the QuickStart Documentation](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html)

Comment: I got it! A little problem with the home router. Even if I have in my main module config the home definition the second one its the default home...

Comment: Define `HomeRoute` - the Configuration of all Modules will be merged. The LoadOrder of the Modules is important. Read [my Blog about understanding ZF2 Configuration](http://samminds.com/2013/04/understanding-zf2-configuration/) for further details. And you may want to either edit your question with more specific details or ask a new one ;)